# Bad CPU type in executable error while running ruby applications on macbook pro

Tags: ruby, macos

I have macbook Pro on which i installed `ruby` via `rbenv`.

```
Mcbook Pro Specs
 Chip: M1 Pro
 MacOs Version: 12.3
```

I have installed ruby version `2.7.6` with rbenv and i have default ruby `2.6.8p205[universal.arm64e-darwin21]` in my `mac`.

When i run the ruby application so it gives me this error

```
Bad CPU type in executable
```

Can any one tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: How do you run the application?

Comment: You probably have an issue with native extensions for some gem. You haven't provided enough information to assist further than that.